# GNU GPL when applied to Data

Tags: gpl

I would like to export the contents of the GCIDE dictionary data from xml format to sql format for sqlite; however, I am concerned how the GNU GPL License impacts my use of the data. To be clear I want the data and not the xml tags inserted into my database. I then plan to create a small app that will make use of that data in sql lite. Does this mean my sqlite database needs to be provided free and open source? Does this mean any apps I create that connect to the database need to be free and open source?

FYI: I plan on making a public facing web application that uses gcide dictionary data.I am not sure if this counts as distribution of the software or not.

Comment: Related reading: **[GNU GPL for data?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14364231/439793)**

Answer (score 2):

IANAL.

I think it depends on whether your app is a 'derived work' of the GCIDE database.  If your app is a general dictionary-interacting app that works with any dictionary you import into it, that's one thing.  But it sounds like your app is fundamentally dependent on the GPL GCIDE database, so the case for it being a derived work is strong.  Derived works of GPL works can be redistributed only if they are distributed in compliance with the GPL.